# How to overlay pyplot visual elements on multiple relplot charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot four different charts using seaborn's relplot, and I want to highlight the same region on each chart. I am trying to accomplish that by overlaying a visual element created with pyplot's axvline and axvspan functions but it is only shown on the last chart of the relplot sequence:

[image: Text]

```
#relplot sequence
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
graph2=sns.relplot(x="variable", y="value",col='Instance_x',data=df_final,kind='line',col_wrap=2, hue='Instance_x',facet_kws={'sharey':False}, ci=None)
graph2.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
graph2.fig.suptitle('Annual Savings per Instance (HA Scenario, AWS)',fontdict= { 'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight':'bold'})
graph2.set_axis_labels('Average Annual Utilization (%)','Average Annual Savings per Virtual machine ($)',fontsize = 14)

for ax in graph2.axes:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(ax.get_yticks().tolist()))
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), size = 13)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))


graph2.axes[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(graph2.axes[0].get_xticks().tolist()))
graph2.axes[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(graph2.axes[1].get_xticks().tolist()))
graph2.axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter())
graph2.axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter())
graph2.axes[0].invert_xaxis()

# pyplot overlay 
plt.axvline(25, color='grey',lw=1.3)
plt.axvline(50, color='grey',lw=1.3)
plt.axvspan(25, 50, alpha=0.2, facecolor='lightgrey')
```

Comment: Link here: https://imgur.com/a/zn0t1pw